# Installing bufferutil package on MAC OSX Yosemite

Tags: node.js, macos

```
npm install bufferutil
```

Installing bufferutil gives me following error, I am not understanding the underlying issue e.g

```
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node
ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Release/bufferutil.node] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:204:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.8.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/sakhunzai/Sites/test/node_modules/bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v5.8.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.8.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "bufferutil"
npm ERR! node v5.8.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.7.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! bufferutil@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bufferutil@1.2.1 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bufferutil package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs bufferutil
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bufferutil
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/sakhunzai/Sites/test/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you try upgrading your copy of Xcode?

Comment: not yet, I am running  10.10.5

Comment: You may also try a workaround as suggested [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2933#issuecomment-142055305): `cd /usr/local/lib sudo ln -s ../../lib/libSystem.B.dylib libgcc_s.10.5.dylib`